# Cannot read property 'cell' of undefined using data table when i add new 3 columns

Tags: javascript, datatable

Trying to fix my problem but i can't resolved it :(
When i add another new 3 columns InventoryId ,CircuitTypeId and LocationId

```
<table
  id="tblServiceNumbersContent"
  class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm table-scroll"
>
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>InventoryId</th>
      <th>CircuitTypeId</th>
      <th>LocationId</th>
      <th class="text-center">
        Service Numbers &nbsp;
        <i id="toggleSeviceNumberFilter" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">Charge Amount</th>
      <th class="text-center" style="z-index: 2;">
        <i
          id="toggleServiceNumbersModal"
          class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"
          data-toggle="modal"
          data-target="#serviceNumbersModal"
        ></i>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="serviceNumberFilterRow">
      <td colspan="4">
        <input
          id="serviceNumberContentFilter"
          type="text"
          class="form-control input-sm"
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tblServiceNumbersContentBody">
    <!-- selected service numbers (from modal) are loaded here -->
  </tbody>
  <tfoot id="tblServiceNumbersContentFooter">
    <!-- Table footer (totals) are being added dynamically -->
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

[HtML][1]

[This is the Javascript][1]

```
var table = $("#tblServiceNumbersContent").DataTable({
  responsive: true,
  dom: '<"top"pl>rt<"bottom"fi><"clear">',
  searching: false,
  ordering: false,
  bInfo: false,
  lengthChange: false,
  language: {
    processing: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw"></i>',
  },
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  searchDelay: 1500,
  ajax: {
    url: "expensemanagement.aspx/GetServiceNumbersFromBillDetails",
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: function (d) {
      var param = JSON.stringify({
        billId: billId,
        draw: d.draw,
        offsetRow: d.start,
        fetchRow: d.length,
        searchCriteria: "", //$('#serviceNumberContentFilter').val()
      });
      return param;
    },
    dataSrc: function (json) {
      json.draw = json.d.draw;
      json.recordsTotal = json.d.recordsTotal;
      json.recordsFiltered = json.d.recordsFiltered;
      json.data = json.d.data;

      $("#expense-management-window").waitMe("hide");

      //loadHideColumns(table);

      var return_data = json;
      return return_data.data;
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
      // Here, manually add the loading message.
      $("#tblServiceNumbersContent > tbody").html(
        '<tr class="odd">' +
          '<td valign="top" colspan="6" class="dataTables_empty">Loading&hellip;</td>' +
          "</tr>"
      );
    },
  },
  columns: [
    { data: "InventoryId" },
    { data: "CircuitTypeId" },
    { data: "LocationId" },
    { data: "ServiceNumber" },
    { data: "ChargeAmount" },
    { data: "ActionDisplay" },
  ],
  action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
    var data = oTable.rows({ selected: true }).data();
    console.log("data---" + data);
  },
});
```

Comment: It would be helpful in debugging if you could provide javascript in text form

Comment: You must have the exact same number of columns in your header as in each <tr> ...You **cannot** use colspan along with DataTables ...